# How to display users facebook news feed after retriving with graph API graphically (not as array) ??

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I,m trying to create a website where users can login with their facebook login and can see their news feed , like comment and update their status. I have seen lots of documentation about it and also was able to retrieve some info using php-sdk . But all the info I retrieved is got as array and I don't know how to display them just like facebook ? Can anyone help me please ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to iterate over the array in php and insert each element of the array into an html tag.  When your html renders in a user's browser, the data will be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Use the array returned to make the webpage by inserting necessary items into html tags and use css to style them..

You can find what you look for here: http://25labs.com/tutorial-integrate-facebook-connect-to-your-website-using-php-sdk-v-3-x-x-which-uses-graph-api/